# How to filter pandas dataframe by a feature value ending with Case sensitive letter

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:
df:

```
C1    C2
Ford  11
ram   13
SUV   19
SEDAN 14
```

I want to filter the data frame column C1 where the C1 values end with a upper case character. So the expected output looks like this:

```
C1    C2
SUV   19
SEDAN 14
```

I tried different regex approaches but nothing worked out for me.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: How about [`[a-z]$`](https://regex101.com/r/9EqacA/1)

Comment: I already tried this but didn't work for me:

df[df['C1'].str.endswith('[A-Z]$')]

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.endswith` doesn't accept regexes, use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df[df['C1'].str.contains('[A-Z]$')]
```

Output:

```
      C1  C2
2    SUV  19
3  SEDAN  14
```